# How to raise an error in template by form.error.as_text?

Tags: python, django

I cant understand how to show error in template without redirecting on error page. 
My task is to check existence of email in database and if its doesnt exist raise an error in form.

Im using Django 2.1 and Python 3.7

What i have: django/auth/views.py

```
class PasswordResetView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html'
    extra_email_context = None
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    from_email = None
    html_email_template_name = None
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')
    template_name = 'registration/password_reset_for.html'
    title = _('Password reset')
    token_generator = default_token_generator

@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    opts = {
        'use_https': self.request.is_secure(),
        'token_generator': self.token_generator,
        'from_email': self.from_email,
        'email_template_name': self.email_template_name,
        'subject_template_name': self.subject_template_name,
        'request': self.request,
        'html_email_template_name': self.html_email_template_name,
        'extra_email_context': self.extra_email_context,
    }
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        form.save(**opts)
        return super().form_valid(form)
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email is not in database')
        return email
```

its standart django class and im just trying to customize it a little bit.
Its works but redirects user on error page.

And here is a form of password reset

```
class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)

def check_email(self, email):
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return email
            else:
                return forms.ValidationError('Email does not exist')
```

Ive tryed to add check method in form but its not working(

And here is code of my template:

```
        {% if form.errors %}
            {{ form.errors.as_text }}
{% endif %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" required="" id="id_email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: have you read the docs? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/)

Comment: Maybe look into wtforms aswell (https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/)